# How to create unique strings every time in iOS?

Tags: ios, unique

How can I create a sequence of characters, that would be random globally.

Actually I want to create some names, every time, and I don't want them to be same again and again.

Thanks

Comment: How about NSUUID? Or arc4random_buf?

Comment: You mean a name that human readable? Create your old array of names get random value by random between 0 and array.count.

Comment: NSUUID is not fine, everytime it will generate same thing. random can be replicate when millions of users does it at a time. @jtbandes

Comment: @ChatarVeerSuthar you are wrong, NSUUID generate different string for each run, ofcourse it's not a natural random function, but it does the job from most use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this also by using `NSDateFormatter` and `NSDate`

```
func getUniqueString() -> String
{
  let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEMMMMyyyyhhmmssa"
  return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
}
```

You can change the `NSDateFormatter` format, but it should contain all elements of date (year, month, day, time).

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
UUID().uuidString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "").lowercased()
```